# excel lambda formula refer the equation to another cell

Tags: excel

i want to make a lambda formula that the equation is referred to another cell like on the `Scenario 2`, but the problem is that thing is doesn't work.
I want thing that work properly like on the `Scenario 1` but using the referred cell like on the `Scenario 2` so i can easier change the equation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is not possible in the way you want it, check this post maybe you find a way to make it works with `EVALUATE` function: https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula. I can not test it with Excel Web.

Comment: Agreed with David. You'd have to do something like defining *MyLambda* in Name Manager as `=LAMBDA(x,EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(A13,"x",x)))` and then calling `=MyLambda(A10)` within the worksheet. Though I can't see a way without passing a hardcoded "x" as string to `SUBSTITUTE`.

Comment: yeah i've tried to use `EVALUATE` formula to do that thing, but the problem with the `EVALUATE` formula is that those are using VBA, and unfortunately on my spreadsheet those thing is unstable and sometimes doesn't make proper calculation, like i need to refresh the spreadsheet so it doesn't output an error results